# Is there a way to create a loc/rot/scale shortcut in the context menu?

Tags: interface, shortcut

This was a feature I got really used to in 3DS Max and I'm wondering if theres a way to create the same shortcut in the context menu instead of hitting the keyboard or mousing to the left of the screen when I want to change it. It was so convenient having it wherever I was at on the screen.

Comment: Unless they change the method implemented in context menu, AFAIK there isn't and shouldn't have that method to include custom shortcut in arbitrary context menu without hard coding source code. If you think this feature should be in Blender out-of-the-box, then a [feature request](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) will be a good way to go.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use a keyboard shortcut?  One blender's biggest, if not the biggest strength, is how powerful and smooth its hotkey system is.  G, R, and S are all there directly under the fingers of the hand you'd otherwise not be using - that's more presence than something behind a context menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Addon update

The original tool set in the left hand side 3D view is extremely complicated so I would rather use a naïve method to add operator in both edit and object mode with following tool:

- Tweak
- Select Box
- 3D Cursor
- Move
- Rotate
- Scale
- Transform

[image]
<sub>The icon is not the one in tool shelf, that's a new stuff and I can't find a easy way to get those icon value. So I use some similar icon instead.</sub>

Indeed pretty handy after using it awhile, should be a useful feature in normal workflow.

```py
...
def menu_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.label(text="Set Tool")
    for key, content in __toolset_list.items():
        if content:
            layout.operator(
                "WM_OT_tool_set_by_id",
                **content
            ).name = key
        else:
            layout.separator()
    layout.separator()
...
```

I put it in [context_menu_toolset.py - GitHub](https://github.com/hikariNTU/BlenderExchangeScript/blob/master/addon/context_menu_toolset.py) so just go download it and run or install the script. If the addon didn't show up after installment, it should be in Test tab rather then Official or Community.

#### Non addon method

In Blender 2.83, use <kbd>space bar</kbd> can call out the operation panel if you set your space bar function to **tools**:

[image]

You can change your preference here:

[image]

You can also assign them directly into quick panel:

[image]

Then use <kbd>Q</kbd> to call out quick menu:

[image]

And you, still, can assign a short cut to the quick menu item:

[image]

Finally, you can directly assign the additional short cut in preference.