# Blender 2.9. Flip Region missing?

Tags: customization

UPDATE:  The "screen: flip region" command from the Menu Search is either accidentally or intentionally missing from both stable, beta, and experimental versions of Blender 2.90.  Downgrading to Blender 2.8x has solved this problem for question A, however even though the Flip Region command can be executed on the panel in question B, it doesn't actually do anything. :(

A.  I am trying to move the Toolbar to the right hand side of the screen.  Is this still possible in Blender 2.9?
In scrolling through the forums, it appears that pre-2.8 there was a "flip side" feature on the toolbar that could be accessed by the search bar with F3. However the feature doesn't appear to exist post 2.8, likely due the appearance on forums that many people were doing this unintentionally and coming here for help reversing it.  Maybe I need to look in a new place?  Any information is appreciated.

B.  Similarly I would like to move this. (I'm not sure what its called so for this post I'm calling it Tool Properties).  Is there a way to move or scale up the Tool Properties or view them in the larger Editor Properties panel as highlighted?
Additionally if someone knows the proper name of the panel please let me know.

[image]

I apologize if these questions have been answered already.  I attempted to find solutions myself but have come up empty.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: That's indeed a toolbar panel, and I don't think it is possible to set it to the right hand side. And the size is also designed as "fix width" which only change when the UI scale factor change. The tool shelf itself belong to the 3D view space so it's unlikely to have it at other panel. Blender doesn't support pure float UI panel now. And this might help you: [interface - Is there a way to create a loc/rot/scale shortcut in the context menu? - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190176/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-loc-rot-scale-shortcut-in-the-context-menu/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
To use this with Blender 2.90 or later, it seems that you have to manually add the keymap of the following command.
Settings> Keymap> Screen>
**screen.region_flip**

As for the name of B's ​​menu, it looks like "Redo Last".
The operator name that calls this menu in a popup is "Redo Last".
**screen.redo_last**

Apparently it was intentionally deleted.
↓ It's not the task of this problem itself, but it says so.

[⚓ T71810 UI: Flipping a Sidebar with more tabs isn't aligned correct](https://developer.blender.org/T71810)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. Thank you [@Bookakuno](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200347/31447).

[image]

1. Open up the User Preferences / Key map / Screen/ Screen(Global)
2. Press <kbd>Add New</kbd>
3. Open up the *textbox on the left* by clicking the little triangle
4. Rename as `screen.region_flip` and set the key to <kbd>F5</kbd>
5. Move the mouse over the *Toolshelf* and press <kbd>F5</kbd>